# Excel reading gives java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, excel, exception

I have tried to read a excel file using jxl. It is giving `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.I don't know why I'm getting that for this code.

```
public class TestExcelReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws BiffException, IOException{
        File file=new File("D:\\TestExcel.xls");
        Workbook workbook=Workbook.getWorkbook(file);  \\Line number 14

        Sheet sheet=workbook.getSheet(0);
        System.out.println("No of rows is "+sheet.getRows()); 
    }

}
```

My exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 68
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jxl.biff.StringHelper.getString(StringHelper.java:164)
    at jxl.read.biff.WriteAccessRecord.<init>(WriteAccessRecord.java:56)
    at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.parse(WorkbookParser.java:821)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:237)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
    at ext.gt.test.TestExcelReader.main(TestExcelReader.java:14)
```

Comment: I'm not getting that..?I'm using `jxl.Workbook` class

Comment: Which line is line 14 in TestExcelReader?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson `Workbook workbook=Workbook.getWorkbook(file);`

Comment: You posted irrelevant code. Please add the code where you are doing index operation on the string.

Comment: I was asking if the `Workbook` class is yours. You exception has its roots in that class, not in this one you've posted.

Comment: Sorry but when running this code I'm getting this irrelevent exception.This is that code :-(

Comment: @GGrec Okay.That's not my class.Actually I've added `jxl.jar`.Class is from that.

Comment: @GGrec From here I think http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: is that an Excel95 file?

Comment: @Alessio Thanks.The same problem I have.You have fix for that??

Comment: So the problem is because of that, the documentation of the library talks about Excel97, and I saw on some other forum that is working only with version after 97

Comment: @Alessio Thank you so much.You saved my day.Post that link as answer so that I can accept

Comment: @Prabhakaran You can take a look at that link

Comment: @SaranyaSharan hmm that library not supported to below Excel97.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using an Excel95 file, and unfortunately it seems that is not supported (only files after Excel97 are).

Take a look here
http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)

and here

http://www.java-forum.org/allgemeine-java-themen/140138-java-tabelle-auslesen-xls-excel-fehler.html

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013 and get the same error StringIndexOutOfBoundException